# What is the subject matter distinction between Worldbuilding SE and Science Fiction & Fantasy SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

After examining a few Worldbuilding posts it seems like this site is about:

> Asking how to envision/create highly imaginative worlds that cover any given question. So the answers to any given question will be very different from any other and the choice of the correct answer completely arbitrary as the answers are about creativity.

So, with this in mind, my question is, how does this site differ from the Science Fiction & Fantasy SE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scifi.SE focuses on existing works of Scientific Fiction and Fantasy, whereas Worldbuilding is to help people who are **developing** worlds of Fantasy/Fiction in various areas.

Comment: Can you please list these areas. Is it books, computer games, or other? Wouldn't dealing ideas from such Worldbuilding SE posts count as plagiarizing? I've seen done really good answers.

Comment: @JackMaddington It's all of the areas you listed and more. The Stack Exchange network has copyrights that allow users to take ideas from the site and use it, IIRC.

Comment: The word is licenses.  Stack Exchange uses the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  But that doesn't matter so much, as copyright only covers the text of the posts.  Most people don't use posts verbatim.  Ideas are not copyrightable.  Also, physical facts are not restrictable under any form of intellectual property.